# Erro ao utilizar window.history.back() do Javascript

Tags: javascript, post, script

Olá,
estou com problemas em utilizar o método ***window.history.back()*** em Javascript, o mesmo tem a funcionalidade de retornar para a página anterior da minha aplicação, o problema é que tenho uma busca do tipo POST nessa página e ao tentar retornar para a página anterior o sistema quebra em virtude de tentar reenviar esse formulário.

Código utilizado:

```js
<button class="tiny" onclick="javascript: window.history.back();" name="btn-back-page">Voltar</button>
```

Mensagem de erro:

[image: Erro ao clicar em Voltar]

Comment: É um comportamento padrão do navegador, pois os dados em POST não são podem ser enviados novamente sem a atorização do usuário, imagine se um POST fosse um UPLOAD, toda vez que o usuário usasse o Voltar iria fazer o upload novamente, dando muitas dores de cabeça, para resolver simplesmente mude sua busca para GET, eu entendo que talvez você queira ocultar a querystring, mas querystring existe por um motivo de facilitar a vida do usuário e até para indexação e histórico mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim é verdade, o browser vai sempre confirmar quando você está voltando para uma página que foi resultado de um POST. Pode não ser o seu caso nesta página, mas poderia ser uma página de compras e ai correria o risco do usuário enviar duas vezes os dados do cartão, uma compra, etc.

Não é muito legal simplesmente tentar "burlar" a segurança do browser nesse sentido. Existem algumas pessoas que tentam usar o `location`, mas não acho que é a solução ideal.

Se você quer fazer um website mais sólido e precisa usar o POST, leia a respeito da estratégia [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Resumindo, esta estratégia faz com que você trabalhe assim, para garantir que o usuário pode usar o retornar do browser (e consequentemente seu script também) sem maiores problemas:

- Sempre que o servidor receber um POST, invés de retornar a resposta diretamente, guarde as variáveis e retorne um 302 (uma cabeçalho de resposta para o browser redirecionar para outra página)
- Esta nova página funciona com o GET, usando as variáveis já setadas
- Se o usuário pressionar o back, ele irá voltar para a página do GET